# Find an element array with try and catch in java

Tags: java, arrays, exception

So, I have two arrays, the first one is people's name and the second one is ages. And then, I made an id in the output so I can find which id I want to print.

For example :

ID        Name       Ages

1         Lucas      15

2         Vulnere    16

But, I want to use try and catch to prevent the user to find an id that outside an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] name = {"Lucas","Vulnere"};
int[] age = {15, 16};
String answer = "";
System.out.println("ID\tNames\tAges");
for(i=0; i < age.length; i++)
{
System.out.println((i+1) +"\t"+name[i]+"\t"+age[i]);
}

do {
try {

System.out.println("Find people by id");
int id = input.nextInt();
}

catch(//WhatExceptionShouldIUse){
System.out.println("Id not found");
}

System.out.println("Result : ");
System.out.println("id : "+id);
System.out.println("Name : "+name[id-1]);
System.out.println("Age : "+age[id-1]);

System.out.println("Want to try to find it again? Y/N");
answer = input.next();
}while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBound

Comment: parrallel arrays are a symptom of bad design https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Comment: also, you need to move `name[id-1]` and `age[id-1]` inside the `try` block

Comment: Consider indenting your code properly if you would like people to try and read it.

Answer (score 2):

You can have it by doing this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds ex) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can surround by try and catch like this:

try{

do stuff...

} catch(Exeption e){
  do stuff..
}

why dont you use List and contain function?